# How get full description from freebase

Tags: freebase

I often get description of person that end in the middle of sentence like this:
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/en/dr_luke

Why it happens and how to get full descriptions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the text came from Wikipedia, Freebase has only a snippet and you need to get the rest (or as much as you want) from Wikipedia.